# Server Side Rendered page not always being rendered correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a very simple NextJS project that has a single page. The app is setup to use redux, next-redux-wrapper and redux thunk. The page should always be server side rendered.

This is what the the page code looks like:

```
pages/index.js
const index = () => {
    const { products } = useSelector((state) => state.productList);

    return {
        products.map((product) => (
            <div key={product._id} className="column is-4-tablet is-3-desktop">
                <FoodItem foodItem={product} />
            </div>
        ));
    }
}

export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(({ store }) => {
  store.dispatch(listProducts());

  return {
    props: {},
  };
});


// pages/_app.js
import { wrapper } from "redux/store";

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
};

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

The strange behaviour I've noticed is that sometimes when the user refreshes the browser, a call is not made to the server to regenerate the page. This causes the page to be empty.

The actual behaviour should be that when the user refreshes the page or navigates to the page, a call should be made to the server to re-render the page.

I'm not sure when sometimes when the user refreshes the page or navigates to the page, the browser does not make a fresh call to the server to get the page re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to NextJS, but I think you should try passing the productList object to the index.js page, rather than useSelector

so return yourObject from getServerSideProps in the props:{yourObject}, then access from index =({yourObject}), then try displaying it

Hope it works...